# Why isn't this out-of-bounds error detected at compile-time?

Tags: rust

I've just started coding in rust for a few days now and have stumbled upon this case here that I don't understand

```
struct Foo {
    arr: [u8; 5]
}

fn main() {
    let foo = Foo{ arr: [0; 5] };
    let bar = &foo;
    println!("{}", bar.arr[100]);
}
```

Why does this code compile? Can't the compiler see that there is an out-of-bounds error there? It can detect it when i try to print `foo.arr[100]`, so what gives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, not all errors that *could* be detected at compile-time will be reported to the compiler. In this case though, it *should* be detected since Rust 1.60 and earlier will report this problem, but Rust 1.61 and 1.62 will not:

```
$ cargo +1.60 build
   Compiling mycrate v0.1.0 (/rust-tests)
error: this operation will panic at runtime
   --> src/main.rs:133:20
    |
133 |     println!("{}", bar.arr[100]);
    |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^ index out of bounds: the length is 5 but the index is 100
    |
    = note: `#[deny(unconditional_panic)]` on by default
```

```
$ cargo +1.61 build
   Compiling mycrate v0.1.0 (/rust-tests)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.78s
```

This has already been reported as [issue #98444: Taking a shared reference of an array suppresses the unconditional_panic lint](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/98444). You can downgrade your toolchain but hopefully it is resolved soon.